# My router block http traffic

Tags: networking, router, http

I'm using a regular commercial router for my network. It's blocking HTTP traffic for some reason I don't know:

```
% curl http://google.com
curl: (56) Recv failure: Operation timed out
```

HTTPS traffic is fine though:

```
% curl https://google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

How can I fix such problem?

Comment: I think we need a bit more info. What is your setup like?

Comment: Your router is not blocking HTTP traffic.

Comment: @Ramhound how can you tell? It certainly looks like a possibility to me!